# Apply WordPress customizer styles to Gutenberg editor

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I have numerous customizer styles in my WordPress theme, and I'm looking at applying those chosen styles (eg, font colour) to the Gutenberg blocks - editor view.

The customizer styles are pulled through to the front-end using: `<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'text_colour', '#222222' ); ?>;`

I am using a .css file to apply styles to the block editor, but how do I convert the `get_theme_mod` into a css style?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wp_add_inline_style() on the post edit screen!?

```
function my_dynamic_editor_styles()
{
    wp_register_style( 'dummy-handle', false );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'dummy-handle' );
    wp_add_inline_style( 'dummy-handle', '* { color: '.get_theme_mod( 'text_colour', '#222222' ).'; }' );
}

add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'my_dynamic_editor_styles', 100 );
```